# What is the keyboard shortcut to focus this textfield in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: xcode, search, file

What is the keyboard shortcut to get focus inside the textbox pointed in the screenshot below?

I am new to Xcode 4.1. I use Eclipse a lot.

In Eclipse if we want to jump over any file we can use Command + Shift + R and we get a popup box and we can start typing filename and it shows suggestion, something similar to it I am looking in Xcode.

[image: xcode 4.1 screen-shot]

Comment: Questions about *using* Xcode are on topic here (development is not). This question is on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its filter Navigator..

And Its shortcut is Command+option+j

Comment: Command-Option-J seems to focus the textfield in the currently open pane of the left navigation. Could be Search, Debugger, etc. I'd like to see a shortcut that *always* focuses the "Filename Search" textfield.